# Bitbucket fails to authenticate on git pull

Tags: git, bitbucket

I use BitBucket and had to change my password because it was compromised.

```
git pull
```

> remote: Invalid username or password. If you log in via a third party service you must ensure you have an account password set in your account profile.
>   fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/myusername/myproject.git/'

How can I change my password using command line?

Comment: Please show contents of `.gitconfig` file in your git repo, and also your local git configuration (`~/.gitconfig` (or `~/.config/git/config` on some distros)).

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: Look at your accepted answer. It's about git configuration.

Comment: Try >> Preference > Account > connect account

Comment: If you are using OAuth to login, try this https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/quot-remote-Invalid-username-or-password-amp-fatal/qaq-p/1076999 (I used google account )

Answer (score 197, accepted):

You need to reset the password as shown below.

On macOS:

```
git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
```

On Windows 10/11:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

After executing this, it prompts you for the user name and password for your repo.

Comment: This frustrated me for 2 hours before I realized I had to restart in order to trigger Git to prompt me for the username and password.

Comment: but where should i put it 
cause i am using plugin of bitbucket  can u guide me??

Comment: Nice! So now I can enter my Atlassian password instead of my old BB password (ugh)

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with Bitbucket or sourcetree, but rather with git itself. Try command if you are using git on linux terminal: git config --global --unset credential.helper

Comment: On linux use: $ git config --global user.password <new_password>

Answer (score 60):

I think is only an authentication problem...

1. Click on your Bitbucket account icon (up right) and go to "Manage account".
2. Go to "Change password" option in left menu.
3. Enter your password in "New password" and "Confirm password" fields.
4. Click on "Change password".

That's all :)

Comment: Yes, actually when i faced with this "If you log in via a third party service you must ensure you have an account password set in your account profile." I just changed my password in settings and everything now works

Comment: This did not work for me. I had reset the password already but my cmd line was not giving me an ability to enter my new password.

Comment: my Extention: after New password was set you have to make Logout and Login to Bitbucked.org (not Atlassian!!!). After this you have to update password on your side (Xcode, SmartGit etc.) and everything will be OK.

Comment: Actually, I just change my account password in web client in bitbucket last night, then I encountered this issue...

Comment: Really need to change the password in order to remove the authentication error. It's working now.

Comment: The solution is obsolete. A password reset is possible via a [web form](https://bitbucket.org/account/password/reset)

Comment: Thanks, couldn't get it to work until I changed my password at Atlassian. It kept complaining my initial password was invalid (new user) but changing it solved it.

Answer (score 50):

First, edit your .git/config and remove your username from 'url'.

I had this:

```
url = https://username@bitbucket.org/pathto/myrepo.git
```

And after modification:

```
url = https://bitbucket.org/pathto/myrepo.git
```

Then try to pull (or push) and use your **email** and password credentials to login.

Comment: I did this but the url change did not show when I tried to push. After doing a pull I got a login screen and subsequently I was able to push, however the old url with the user name still displays in the push dialog

Comment: This worked for me. Using SourceTree go to settings in the top right, Remotes, and then edit the url path.

Comment: Thanks! This trick actually worked. After fetching, I had to re-enter my login (email) and password, and it finally worked again.

Answer (score 33):

Lately, BitBucket needs you to generate an App Password:

**Settings/Access Management/App Passwords.**

[https://bitbucket.org/account/user/.../app-passwords](https://bitbucket.org/account/user/your-username/app-passwords)

Comment: This resolved it for me, and then I used the App Password for SourceTree instead of my original password

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me as well when attempting a fresh clone with a google-authenticated bitbucket account - I can't believe it took so long to find this answer buried halfway down in stack overflow.

Comment: This is the only solution to resolve my problem that was happening long :)

Comment: It happened suddenly and for only one of my repos... Nothing worked, only this. Thank you

Comment: yes this did resolved nicely

Answer (score 22):

If you are a mac user this worked for me:

1. open Keychain Access.
2. Search for Bitbucket accounts.
3. Delete them.

Then it will ask you for the password again.

Comment: I know it may be off topic, but I use SourceTree, and found this thread helpful. BUT I needed to also remove my account in the SourceTree app, and then enter it again, in addition to removing the entries in the System KeyChain.

Answer (score 15):

I needed to do this and run a git pull in order to set my password from the command line in order to get this working.

Note this method saves your password in a plain text file on your disk:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
git pull
```

Other solutions here:
[Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github)

Answer (score 10):

I clicked on this button and it worked for me.

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Don't just use a picture. Describe *what button* you clicked and, of course, why you expect that to be useful for this.

Answer (score 8):

If you've changed the password on Windows 10, go to credential manager and update the password:

> [image: go to credential manager and update the password]

Answer (score 6):

You can update your Bitbucket credentials from the OSX Keychain.

**Updating your cached credentials via the command line:**

```
$ git credential-osxkeychain erase
host=bitbucket.org
protocol=https
[press return]
```

If it's successful, nothing will print out. To test that it works, try and clone a repository from Bitbucket. If you are prompted for a password, the keychain entry was deleted.

Answer (score 5):

If you found authentication error problem when you entered correct password and username it's git problem. To solves this problem when you are installing the git in your machine uncheck the enable git credential manager
 [image]

Answer (score 3):

I was facing same error, But I didn't need to change my password.

Just go to `bitbucket->preferences->accounts` select your account and check if your password is correct.

In my case, my password was messed up. Just corrected my password and it worked.

Comment: for me in Bitbucket's web interface, there is no "preferences > accounts" link.

Comment: I was using sourcetree desktop App

Answer (score 3):

This answer is for SO users who browse here after searching for the error.

- Terminal will not accept your Bitbucket or Atlassian web app password if
  your account is associated with an Atlassian (Jira) account. If this
  is your case, you have a giant string generated for you that you can
  find in your MacOSX keychain app. This is the password Terminal accepts.
- It is not clear how to re-generate this password or re-set it to match what
  Bitbucket will accept.
- Changing password in SourceTree's settings did not work for me.
- Changing password in Atlassian account profile did not work for me.
- Bitbucket does not have a link or interface to change password for
  this case in the Bitbucket account profile - user has to go to
  Atlassian account profile.

In my case, nothing worked because I changed my username in Bitbucket.

Atlassian and Bitbucket are not completely integrated. Bitbucket uses the Atlassian user email and web app password, but allows you to have a different username.

There seems to be a bug in this process, especially since it's not clear which application or process is generating the authentication and where it's stored or editable. Changing the username breaks authentication.

There may be a way to update the username used by the credentials and Bitbucket, but I was already several hours behind when I discovered that **changing my username back to what it was before restored authentication.**

Answer (score 3):

For me the issue was I changed my username so the git url also got changed.
So I had to set the new git url using

```
git remote set-url origin <URL>
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it happens when you change the remote bitbucket account password.

**Solution**

```
Go to Control panel => User Accounts => Credential Manager => Windows Credentials => move to Generic credentials and change the password of account
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Firstly reset your password at "https://id.atlassian.com"
2. Ensure you
   are able to login to Bitbucket Cloud -  "https://bitbucket.org"
3. Clear stored credentials on your machine
   a. Windows: Navigate to Credential Manager and clear stored credentials related to Bitbucket
   Cloud.
4. Mac OS X: Navigate to Keychain Access and clear stored
   credentials related to Bitbucket
5. Cloud Once this is done, try to
   login to perform a git operation authenticating to Bitbucket Cloud
   once again.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the issue on Windows 10 after changing my password for bitbucket. I just opened `git bash` in my repo location; Wrote command for

```
git push --set-upstream origin <branch_name>
```

It opened git credential manager window and asked for credentials. I entered the new one and it pushed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question, but I thought I would provide the solution that worked for me. I signed up for bitbucket using my google account and did not have a password. Turns out the password is my Atlassian account password. If you have an Atlassian account then try this password to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

For myself only a combination of the approaches by @software-is-fun and @dev-adgh1 worked.

The cause was, that I changed my password (SSO) and did not use a token for our company repository. I am using Windows 10 and this is the only repository I wanted to have this authentication credentials be used.

So I did the following:

1. **Execute** `git config --local credential.helper store` in the directory where my repository was located
2. **Erase** the file %USERPROFILE%\**.git-credentials**, so eg c:\users\username.git-credentials (have a look at it first to not throw your other credentials away)

3. Open the **Windows Credential Manager**, Open Windows Credentials, **Delete** the **credentials** for the repository in use
4. **Execute** a `git pull` in your local repository directory and get prompted with the new login (where I entered my username and the token - not the password).

Working :)

Answer (score 0):

This helps me.

Run `git remote -v` to see the current remote URL.

```
$ git remote -v
origin https://emmap1@bitbucket.org/tutorials/tutorials.git.bitbucket.org.git  (fetch)
origin https://emmap1@bitbucket.org/tutorials/tutorials.git.bitbucket.org.git  (push)
```

Update the remote URL with git remote set-url using the current and new remote URLs.

```
$ git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:tutorials/tutorials.git
```

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/app-passwords/

Answer (score -1):

I solved it this way.

If you use sourcetree, go to tools->options->Authentication->Accouns Edit and Authentication OK. Then, when i tried again no problem.