# Setting up GitLab to update a Bitbucket project

Tags: git, gitlab, bitbucket, push

In GitLab, I can set up [pushing to a remote repo](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/05/10/feature-highlight-push-to-remote-repository/), which I'd like to use for mirroring my GitLab project on Bitbucket. I set up 2 [secret variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/#secret-variables), `BITBUCKET_USERNAME` and `BITBUCKET_PASSWORD` w/ respective values. Then, under my GitLab project > Settings > Repository, I check "Remote mirror repository", set "Git Repository URL" to

`https://$BITBUCKET_USERNAME:$BITBUCKET_PASSWORD@bitbucket.org/xxx/yyy.git`,

uncheck "Only protected branches" and save the changes. Supposing I'm done, I hit the "Update now" button and get (after some time)

> 2:remote: Invalid username or password. If you log in via a third
>   party service you must ensure you have an account password set in your
>   account profile.
>   fatal: Authentication failed for
>   '[FILTERED]@bitbucket.org/xxx/yyy.git/'

What am I doing wrong? The "ensure you have an account password set in your account profile" part is especially confusing (where else could one set it?).

EDIT: Investigated this a bit further. First, it seems you absolutely cannot set the password in your account profile, as it's now done over a [web form](https://bitbucket.org/account/password/reset). Second, resetting the Bitbucket password (and changing BITBUCKET_PASSWORD) didn't help. Third, unticking "Protected" next to BITBUCKET_PASSWORD and BITBUCKET_USERNAME also didn't help

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33564295/2520275

Comment: The solution seems obsolete (see my edit)